# How to deal with files on server Silverlight

Tags: c#, sqlite, silverlight-4.0, file

I would to have the ability to connect to a SQLite database file, I am using a C# SQLite Library but due to Silverlight's permissions I can not make a connection to actually locate the file, Can anybody help with actually using the file to execute queries on to?

Thanks.

Comment: the database file is on the server, right?

Comment: Yes the Database file will be on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite is an embedded database which means that only the process hosting it can use it and run queries against it. If you want to connect to a database on the server, you have to expose it through a service (SOAP, WCF, WCF RIA Services) or a REST endpoint.

Using SQLite with Silverlight only makes sense if you want to store files locally.